# $post in Kohana view

Tags: php, kohana

I have write a form code, value is saving in database properly:

```
<?php echo Form::open();  ?>
<?php echo Form::label('name', 'Name') ?>
<?php echo Form::input('name', $post['name']) ?>
<input type="submit" name="Submit">
<?php echo Form::close(); ?>
```

but i have a problem in view, i have got an error-- 
Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\application\views\contact\contact.php on line 51

```
<?php echo Form::input('name', $post['name']) ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: name` this kind of error is easy to spot.

Comment: Where `$post` coming from? Or, could it be `$_POST` global that you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is view part. I am saving the value vai controller.

Comment: The error is saying that $post exists, but $post['name'] doesn't exist in that array.

Comment: thanks. It's working fine. <?php echo Form::input('name') ?>

Answer (score 0):

when you load your page first time the values will not get in post. so that you need to check post is set or not.

```
<?php echo Form::open();  ?>
<?php echo Form::label('name', 'Name') ?>
<?php echo Form::input('name', isset($post['name'])?$post['name']:"" ) ?>
<input type="submit" name="Submit">
<?php echo Form::close(); ?>
```

So now if $post['name'] is set it ll give the post value. other wise no problem.